# How can I step through the Xamarin.Android source code in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I am working on a cross platform project using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 Professional. I am facing a `NotSupportedException` and I can see the corresponding [line of source code on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/src/Mono.Android.Export/CallbackCode.cs#L252).

However I need to fully understand what is going on there, so my question is: **How can I step through the Xamarin.Android (aka Mono.Android) source code inside Visual Studio 2015?**

To further explain the issue: I see the "Frame not in module" message in VS if I break at the point where the exception is thrown. Visual Studio offers me to view the disassembly, which I would rather not like to see...
Also it is not enough just to see the callstack. I need to know what parameters are being passed.

Comment: Try with ReSharper

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou Xamarin.Android is open source, why would ReSharper be necessary?

Comment: So do I have to manually find the correct version and download/checkout the source files and point VS to the right directory on my drive and that's it?

Comment: @RichardSzalay: It is bit complex to debug through it although it is open source. You will have to keep a local repository and add it to your solution. With ReSHarper you can either decompile on the fly or just configure the debug symbols and it will fetch the source code by it self.

Comment: @markus that is pretty much what you have to do.. if you go for the manual way